# What is the earliest reference to Simchas Torah as being the day to finish the Torah cycle?

Tags: torah-reading, simchat-torah, parashat-vezot-habracha

The universal practice, it seems, is to delay the final portion of the Torah, beginning with Devarim 33:1, until Simchas Torah. This portion is then read as the Yom Tov reading, along with the beginning of Bereishis.

What is the earliest mention of this practice, that Vezos HaBeracha be delayed from a usual Shabbos until Simchas Torah?

Comment: Your "mazal" (and mine) of having your question a dupe of mine, which is still unanswered. I'll be giving you an incentive - Look for a bounty on this soon. If for no other reason, I can't award myself my own bounty ;-) Hopefully, you can find something.

Comment: We should have a practice of merging dupes so the Question would be more general and more clear.

Comment: Your Title about S"T connections to the yearly cycle (which is not a dupe) does not correlate with your question which is about moving the Parasha to S"T instead of Shabbos. Please edit either.

Comment: @AlBerko You should suggest it on Meta. As for the second comment - why does it matter now that this is closed as an exact duplicate of DanF’s question?

Comment: Because your title is a completely different question.